# How to use single dataset for multiple tables in a single reportDesign in BIRT tool?

Tags: birt, birt-deapi

Is it possible to use single dataset for multiple tables in a single reportdesign document. Whereas data has repeating transactions for particular table. If yes, then please let me know how to define xPath in dataset.

Sample Data xml:

How to map this books array to table1 and videos array to table2 in single reportdesign?

Comment: Sample data xml :
<library>
<books>
<book>1</book>
<book>2</book>
<book>3</book>
</books>
<audio></audio>
<videos>
<video>1</video>
<video>2</video>
<video>3</video>
</videos>
</library>

Comment: I rarely use XML datasete (only SQL), so I cannot help you with XPath for the exacty syntax, but I can tell you that this is of course possible.

Comment: I have tried to make the xpath as: library/*/* but through this only one table data fetches properly rest of the data comes as null or repeated .

Comment: You need to parametrize your dataset and supply a different value for the parameter in the dataset parameter binding for the two tables.

Comment: Can you please elaborate because as per my understanding it will create two datasets.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known limitation in Birt. Birt will only allow one table in the same report for each data set. any additional tables must be linked to different data sets. Never to the one and same data set.